# How to Clone a Windows Forms Control

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, clone

I have a C# Form that has a Groupbox.  The user must input any desired number (integer) and when the user clicks "ADD", the group box must be duplicated and pasted on the same form based on the number the user inputted. How do I create an exact copy of the GroupBox and paste it in the same form? Please see the attached screenshot.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

I used Sriram's code but the form only adds 2 groupBox:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int containers = 0;
        int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out containers);

        for (int i = 0; i < containers; i++)
        {
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(groupBox1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So when user presses add you need to show two groupboxes with same values ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes sir.  If the user enters 5 in the Number of Containers and clicks "ADD", the number of groupboxes widisplayed in the form should be 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest you to create a user control which has the groupbox you shown with the child controls.

Let's call it as `MyUserControl` so when you create instance of `MyUserControl` you get all controls with the groupbox.

To show the controls without overlapping each other you can use `FlowLayoutPanel` which arranges the controls automatically. Then in button click code you'd just write

```
void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int contaniners = 0;
    int.TryParse(txtContainers.Text, out contaniners);

    for (int i = 0; i < contaniners; i++)
    {
        flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(new MyUserControl());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi sir, how do I create a User Control?

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388333/how-to-use-usercontrol-in-window-forms-programming-c-sharp) helps

Comment: I used the code that you provided. When I click Add, regardless of the number I inputted, the form only adds 1 groupbox to the flowLayoutPanel. How come? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure? update your question with your current button click code

Comment: Do as I suggested, you're adding the same `groupBox1` instance again and again, that won't work. you need to create **new** control. You can see in my code `new MyUserControl()`, that will work.

Comment: Hi Sriram, I am new to C# and I do not know how to create a Control. How should can I create a Control?

Comment: Take a look at the links provided here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388333/how-to-use-usercontrol-in-window-forms-programming-c-sharp

Comment: Hi Sriram, your code worked perfectly! Thank you very much. Does the flow layout panel support scrollbars in cases wherein I input 50 groupboxes?

Comment: Yes it supports. Just set `flowLayoutPanel.AutoScroll = true;`

Comment: just a follow up question. Let's say I inputted 20 containers. Will those 20 containers be the same? Or are they 20 difference instances of the User Control?

Comment: They are 20 different instances, each can hold different values

Comment: Yes, I Figured. However, I cannot seem to read the contents of each User Control. How do I access the values of each User Control?

Comment: You need to add a property in `MyUserControl` for each property you need to access, then use this code. `MyUserControl control = (MyUserControl)flowLayoutPanel.Controls[0];  string dg = control.DG;`  `DG` is the property you're going to add now. You can do it easily by exposing textboxes as public in `MyUserControl` but I'll not recommend that.

Comment: How can I expose the textbox as public?